# Rails returns outdated information after doing a save()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model Question which has_many Options.

In an action I modify the Options of the a Question object and then return the Question object as a json. (This is used in an ajax call). The problem is, the returned json is not up to date and doesn't reflect the modifications I made.

```
def action
  question = Question.find(:id)
  question.options.each do |op|
     op.blah += 1
  end

  respond_to do |format|
     if question.save()
         format.json { render json: {question: question.to_json(:include => :options)} }
     else
         blah blah
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: due to caching? or have you tried loading the options in the console to see if you have successfully modified?

Comment: After refreshing the page, the changes do show up. I also checked the db and the changes are occurring, it is most likely due to caching or some type of scoping issue. hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird because you edit the items in place, then save (and verified that they are saved to db --since refresh works). So the render to json should work.

You could always do explict `reload` calls, like

```
format.json { render json: {question: question.reload.to_json(:include => :options)} }
```

But it would be very weird if that would be the cause, since you actually just saved that data.

But yesterday I had a similar problem, and actually what happened that I did a `replaceHtml` of a `div`, but my inserted data did not have the same surrounding `div`. So the first time it updated correctly, and the second time it just showed the old data (while in fact it did nothing, because it did not find the div to replace).

So in short: if simply refreshing works, imho it is not the database and it is not caching, but will most likely be something in your javascript: the updating of the screen that is going wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I figured out what's going on. I'm actually updated the option and the question separately through a different piece of the code. That's why the question object isn't getting updated. Reload worked though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
question.options.each do |op|
     op.blah += 1
     op.save
end
```

You forgot to save options after modification.

Comment: Oh, simply saving the question doesn't automatically save all its associated models?

Comment: Hmm, don't sure, also why you have question.save(), and not question.save ?

Comment: Question,find(:id) should be Question.find(:id)

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a typo while I was writing this question. The actual code had it right.